# Unable to find the reference Microsoft.DirectX

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, directx, direct3d

I am VERY new to DirectX. I have made a small Kinect-based wpf application in C#, and I want to use DirectX APIs for working with 3D models and Kinect.

I have done a lot of search, but am still unable to find the reference to Microsoft.DirectX.

I right click references -> Add Reference. Then I browse to C:\Windows\Microsoft .NET\ but there is no folder named DirectX or similar.

And that's why when I write

> using Microsoft.DirectX;

it gives me an error

> The type or namespace name 'DirectX' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'(are you missing an assembly reference?)

Please explain to me where I can find the assembly reference and add it in the project??

I am using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10, 64 bit

Comment: Mabye not in the microsoft .net folder, since directx isn't .net?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to use a .NET wrapper for DirectX, that namespace was available as part of [DirectX 9.0 for Managed Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb318658%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which was abandoned by Microsoft around a decade ago in favor of XNA, which is also now abandoned.  I forget whether XNA kept the Microsoft.DirectX namespace.  There was also managed DirectX support on Windows Phone for a while.  These days if you want a managed wrapper for DirectX on Windows desktop, your best bet is probably [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/), which is still under active development.  (Be aware, though, that SharpDX doesn't use the same class structure as Managed DirectX or XNA, so whatever documentation you have that's referencing Microsoft.DirectX probably won't be much use to you when working with SharpDX.)

Comment: You can also move to using [SlimDX](https://slimdx.org/) which is intended to be a direct replacement for the old legacy Managed DirectX 1.1 components.  XNA did not use the same namespace, but the graphics for it was based on the Managed DirectX 2.0 Beta components.